# Euclidean algorithm for two poloynomials

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Find the $gcd(x^8, x^6+x^4+x^2+x+1)$ using the euclidean algorithm.

$x^8 = (x^2)(x^6+x^4+x^2+x+1)+(-x^6-x^4-x^3-x^2)$
$(x^6+x^4+x^2+x+1)=(-1)(-x^6-x^4-x^3-x^2)+(-x^3+x+1)$
$(-x^6-x^4-x^3-x^2)=(x^3)(-x^3+x+1)+(-2x^4-2x^3-x^2)$

I'm not quite too sure where to go from here because $deg(-2x^4-2x^3-x^2)
>deg(-x^3+x+1)$. Did I factor incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your work as:

$$\begin{align}
\gcd(x^8, x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1) & = \gcd(x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1, -x^6 - x^4 - x^3 - x^2)\\
& = \gcd(-x^6 - x^4 - x^3 - x^2, -x^3 + x + 1)\\
& = \gcd(-x^3 + x + 1, -2x^4 - 2 x^3 - x^2)\\
\end{align}
$$

Since $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b,a)$, you're fine.  Just keep at it.